# awk to match file1 with file2 and output matches

Tags: awk

I am trying to use `awk` to match file1 with file2 and print the lines that match in a separate file. File1 is ~4MB and I am getting the below error and I can not seem to fix it.  Thank you :).

```
awk 'NR==FNR{c[$0]; next} ($0 in c)' RS="," file1.txt RS="\n" file2.txt > match.txt
```

> awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767
>   FILENAME="sort.2.txt" FNR=1 NR=1

**File1**

```
chr1:3063265-3063458 AVP:exon.3 8.55959
chr1:947806-947967 RSPO4:exon.3 246.54
chr2:12758246-12758422 CTD-2192J16.22:exon.2;MAN2B1:exon.1;MAN2B1:exon.20;MAN2B1:exon.22 221.483
chr2:57975642-57975745 KIF5A:exon.1;KIF5A:exon.23;KIF5A:exon.26 222.932
```

**File2**

```
AVP
KIF5A
```

**Desired output**

```
chr1:3063265-3063458 AVP:exon.3 8.55959
chr2:57975642-57975745 KIF5A:exon.1;KIF5A:exon.23;KIF5A:exon.26 222.932
```

Comment: Setting `RS=","` for sort.2.txt looks a bit suspicious. Is that really what you want to do? Everything will be considered a field until awk finds a comma, and I don't see any commas in your sample file. (Also it would help if you named your sample files the same as in your command.)

Comment: I have renamed the file names to match. I apologize as I thought I did that. I will remove the `RS=","` from file1 as I am trying to output each line that matches file2 in a separate file (match). Thank you :).

Comment: It can be simpler, try `grep -Ff file2 file1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try,

```
awk '
    FNR==NR{d[$0]; next;}          #Store each key to find, from file2
    {                              #for each line in file1
        for(k in d){               #for each key in d (file2)
            pat="(^|;)"k":";       #pattern to search (regular expression)
            if($2 ~ pat){
                print;             #print if match with RE
                break;
            }
        }
    }' file2 file1
```

you get,

```
chr1:3063265-3063458 AVP:exon.3 8.55959
chr2:57975642-57975745 KIF5A:exon.1;KIF5A:exon.23;KIF5A:exon.26 222.932
```